# CountdownTimer onTick() not getting called

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I'm using a simple `CountDownTimer` and calling the `onTick()` every millisecond:

```
    final int[] i = new int[1];

    CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(1000, 1) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.i("Time left", millisUntilFinished + "");
            i[0]++;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Log.i("i = ", i[0] + "");
        }
    };
```

The problem is though the timer is finishing-up in the correct time, but the `onTick()` method is not getting called every millisecond. Few of the milliseconds get missing everytime.

I checked it using the logs and found that the value of `i[0]` was 597 at the end, whereas it should be 999, as it gets +1 every time `onTick()` is called. Is there a precision error?

Comment: this is because some ticks are skipped since your `countDownInterval` is extremely small (compared to `onTick` execution time), see: http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/CountDownTimer.java#140, try removing  `Log.i` from `onTick` and compare results

Comment: `i[0]` increased from 597 to 613. @pskink, the problem is I want to call a method once only when a specific time in millisecond hits. I tried to do it this way, but `onTick()` keeps skipping milliseconds and my method doesn't get called. Currently I'm fixing it by keeping a global boolean flag to check if the method gets called and increasing the period of onTick.

If there's a limit-time-period of when does onTick starts getting screwed, what is it?

Comment: why dont you just use `Handler#postDelayed(runnable, your_delay_in_ms)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create handler like this:

```
Handler timer = new Handler();
timer.postDelayed(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
        public void run() {
            // Make something
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well somtime due to load on main thread it skips some digits, otherwise it works perfectly.

```
 new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long durationSeconds=millisUntilFinished/1000;
               Log.e("Time","String.format("%02d:%02d", (durationSeconds % 3600) / 60, (durationSeconds % 60))");
                   }

            public void onFinish() {
                Log.e("Time Up!","");                   

            }
```

Comment: I don't think internet speed should have a role in it. My app anyway doesn't have the internet permission.

Comment: @user5038993 yeah.. actually it has no role. Due to load on main thread, somtimes it shows such behaviour otherwise works fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // To-do
            }
        });
    }
};

timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Handler. Try this:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable countDownTimer = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1);
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(countDownTimer, 0);
```

Here first the handler will be called immediately. After that it gets called every millisecond.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't call:

```
countdown.start();
```